# Persistency in Tableau

Tags: dashboard, calculated-field, calculation, tableau-api

I am trying to calculate Persistency in Tableau report.

Persistency: This is a measure of how efficiently an adjuster (or claims office) is working through their claims. The calculation is simple:

Number of Claims,  ( OPEN at Beginning of Month – OPEN at End of Month ) / (OPEN at Beginning of Month) as a Percent.

So if an adjuster has 100 open claims on 4/1, 10 new claims are opened in April, and adjuster closes/settles 40 claims, leaving 70 open on 4/30. Persistency = (100-70)/100 = 30%

I have datasheet with Claim Numbers and their respective "Date Of Report" as well as their "Close Date". I am confused how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: could you please provide any dataset sample?

Comment: Are any of the claims still open? Do they have a null value for the Close date?

Comment: Hi @alex, Yes there are many claims still open with future close dates. Those claims have to be included.

Comment: How Is a future close date represented? As a null value?

Comment: Yes, They have been assigned a future date for example 12-31-9999

Answer (score 0):

I hope the Data looks similar to this
[Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWOPa.png)

With this let us try to find the Open Claims for Previous month and Open claims for current month
To find the previous open claims, I have used the following code

```
if 
MONTH([Current Date])<>MONTH([Report Date])
and
[Status]="Open" then 1 end
```

For current open claims

```
if 
MONTH([Current Date])=MONTH([Report Date])
and
[Status]="Open" then 1 end
```

Now, with this, let us try to calculate Persistency

```
(SUM([Previous Open Claims])-SUM([Current Open Claims]))/SUM([Previous Open Claims])
```

Hope this works! Please let me know if you have more clarification!

Comment: Hi @manoraj, Above calculations isn't giving the correct answer. I guess we ignoring the Close Date which has to be considered.

Comment: Hi! I would like to see your data structure. 
The calculated field will work only if you have the data structure as I have there in the link. Showing your data structure will help me help you better